# English present for a non-English child?

Tags: toddler, language, presents

I would like to gift a Disney-themed item to a Dutch child (Turning 3 in May). However, I'm buying this present in the USA, so everything will be in English.

Should I stay away from English-speaking plushies or English books, or will it be fine to gift something like this?

I remember having a talking Pooh when I was little and I loved it, so I would love to give something similar.

Comment: Is it likely that the child will eventually learn English? (From what I know, it seems that a lot of people in Europe learn English to some degree, but having never been there I'm not sure.)  Do you think the child will even care?

Comment: @Becuzz Yeah she will eventually learn English! I doubt the child cares, she'll probably just see an adorable plushie that makes sounds. I just want to make sure I'm not messing up her learning Dutch language as I have no experience with children at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what could happen (not really having any experience like that), but I can't imagine one talking toy could undo or really disrupt learning her native language.  She's surrounded by Dutch all day, everyone (presumably) speaks to her in Dutch and she responds in the same tongue.  I can't see one toy undoing all those other influences.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337: Young children can easily handle growing up with two different languages and speak them fluently as they grow up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If possible, it would be nice to ask the parents. They may want to delay the introduction to English until formal schooling in order to encourage better usage and avoid undermining primary language acquisition.

If it's not possible to check with them first, it would not be too presumptuous to buy the gift. It's objectively unlikely to have any strong impact on language with few phrases repeated infrequently and I don't think anyone would be reasonably upset with you.